# Click on specific window witch pywinauto

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, python-2.7, pywinauto

I'm trying to click inside an Android emulator window, but it always clicks on my screen (outside the emulator window), could you please help me click on the emulator window? Sry my bad english.

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Application

pwa_app = Application().connect(title_re='HCTR8') #<--- window name
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'HCTR8')#<--- window name
window = pwa_app.window(handle=w_handle)
pywinauto.mouse.click(button='left', coords=(25, 490)) #coords on emulator
```

Comment: Use Appium for Android UI automation. pywinauto is for desktop automation only.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov 
I'm trying to develop a system in Python that I can click at a certain point on the screen in the emulator ...

Comment: Appium can do that. Python is supported AFAIK. Regarding pywinauto approach it's probably necessary to click twice: first click enables emulator mouse capture, second one should happen inside emulator. But for general Android automation you need other tools definitely. They can access text properties using Android native functions.